# Replacing the specific values in columns of data frame using gsub in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have data.frame as follows

```
> df
ID      Value
A_001   DEL-1:7:35-8_1 
A_002   INS-4l:5_74:d
B_023   0 
C_891   2
D_787   8
E_865   DEL-3:65:1s:b
```

I would like replace all the values in the column Value that starts with DEL and INS with nothing. I mean i would like get the output as follows

```
> df
ID      Value
A_001   
A_002   
B_023   0 
C_891   2
D_787   8
E_865
```

I tried to achieve this using gsub in R using following code but it didnt work

```
gsub(pattern="(^([DEL|INS]*)",replacement="",df)
```

Could anyone guide me how to achieve the desired output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just remove the character class and add `.*` next to that group. `sub` alone would do this job.

```
df$value <- sub("^(DEL|INS).*", "", df$value)
```

Inside a character class, each char would be treated speartely not as a whole string. So `[DEL]` would match a single character from the given list, it may be `D` or `E` or `L` .

Answer (score 5):

First letter is not digital:

```
df$value <- gsub("^\\D.*", "", df$value)
```

Or there is '-' in delete value:

```
df$value <- gsub(".*-.*", "", df$value)
```