# gsub returns matrix of numbers instead of replacing string

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I'm trying to use R for the first time and want to do something that seems fairly simple without much success.

I have the following Data Frame [image]

I'am trying to keep only the date in the column Review.LastUpdate.Date.Time using :

```
gsub("T[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}Z", "", DataFrameName)
```

I'm pretty sure it should work but the data frame remains unchanged and the console gets filled with what looks like a matrix full of numbers... (sorry I can't describe it more precisely, I have no idea what this is). It looks like something like this :

```
[1] "c(1,1,1,1,1, \n, 1,1,1,1,1,\n)"
```

Comment: You are applying the `gsub` on the entire dataset instead of a column. A modification of your code would be `gsub("T[0-9]{2}\\:[0-9]{2}\\:[0-9]{2}Z", "", DataFrameName[[2]])`

Comment: and you need to assign the result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051184/replacing-the-specific-values-in-columns-of-data-frame-using-gsub-in-r

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494216/extract-date-in-r

Comment: awesome, thank you very much. I misunderstood the gsub function.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to extract the 'Date' part from the second column of the dataset ('df1')

```
as.Date(df1[[2]])
```

NOTE: It is better not to use regex on DateTime objects

Answer (score 1):

To target the 8th column :

```
gsub("T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z","",DataFrameName[[8]])
```

The gsub function just returns the values extracted. They need to be assigned to the column of "DataFrameName" :

```
DataFrameName$Review.Last.Update.Date.and.Time <- gsub("T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}Z","",DataFrameName[[8]])
```